# Multithreading C# stop thread from ending

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a new thread, which contains only this code:

```
void myThread()
{
    new Form1().Show();
}
```

Keeping it generic for questions sake.

How could i stop this thread from ending? Because the thread ends, the form closes. How could i continue the thread going, so that the form can stay open, and still trigger events (such as button clicks, etc.)

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Well, in general, stopping a thread from ending is simple: 'while(true){stuff};'.  Before you go any further, however, you should look up 'Invoke' and/or 'BeginInvoke'.

Comment: Why do you want to start a new thread for GUI Events?

Comment: I didn't want to go into detail, to avoid over complicating. But i need it to register events, and mixed in with another thread that included OpenGL meant that it could not detect events due to the loops used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're using multithreading to display an additional form, you should call `Application.Run(Form)` instead.
Edit: Just to be clear, the `Application.Run` method won't end before the form is *closed*. All event and such will work.

Comment: I'm no expert on threads, but I've used this way plenty of times and the program never unexpectedly crashed.

Comment: So far, although i've only been using it for a few hours, i've had no issues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

How about showing the form modally - although why would you want to create a new thread to display a form?

```
void myThread()
{
   new Form1().ShowDialog();
...
```

Just to be clear - I believe this will effectively lock your new thread until the form is closed.

Answer (score -2):

It's easy just put an infinite loop in your thread e.g:

```
void myThread()
{
    new Form1().Show();
    while(true)
      {
       Thread.Sleep(16);
      }
}
```

Why am I sleeping the thread? ...because running an infinite loop with nothing inside is quite CPU intensive considering the extremely fast iterations. A sleep of 16 ms gives you like 60 fps which is more than enough for responsiveness you may desire.
Anyway, why do you need to display the form in a separate thread?

Comment: i guess the thread should end, if the form is closed. so that makes no sense. additionally the message queue is not processed

Comment: I just answered how to keep the thread alive... where this perfectly makes sense.. if the user wants to kill the thread they can obviously do so :)